# SRSS: Dynamic amount of subreports in a report

Tags: dynamic, service, reporting, subreport

it might be possible I'm searching for the wrong keywords, but so far I couldn't find anything useful.
My problem is quite simple: At the moment I get a list of individual Ids through a report parameter, I pass them to a procedure and show the results.

The new request is like this: Instead of showing the list for all individuals at once, there should be a list for each individual id.

Since I'm quite a beginner in srss, I thought the easiest approach would be the best: Create a subreport, copy the shown list, and create a subreport per individual id.

The amount of this IDs is dynamic, so I have to create a dynamic amount of subreports.

Funny enought, this doesnt seem to be possible. This http://forums.asp.net/t/1397645.aspx url doesnt show exactly the problem, but it shows the limit of the subreports.

I even ran trough the whole msdn pages starting http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220581.aspx but I couldnt find anything there.

So is there a possibility, to create a loop like:
For each Individual ID in Individual IDs, create a subreport and pass ONE ID to this?

Or is there another approach I should use to make this work?

I tried to create a 'Fake'-Dataset with no sql query but just for iterating the id list, but it seems the dataset needs a data-source...

As usual, thanks so far for all answers!

Matthias Müller

Answer (score 0):

> Or is there another approach I should use to make this work?

You didn't provide much detail about what sort of information needs to be included in the subreport, but assuming it's a small amount of data (say, showing a personnel record), and not a huge amount (such as a persons sales for the last year), a List might be the way to go.

> I tried to create a 'Fake'-Dataset with no sql query but just for iterating the id list, but it seems the dataset needs a data-source...

All datasets require a data source, though if you're merely hard-coding some fake return data, *any* data source will do, even a local SQL instance with nothing in it.